# My page crashes when I try to retrieve information from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm having some issues with my PHP script.

I have a PHP function which is stored in a PHP file, and I'm trying to run that PHP function from another script.

So to explain myself with code:

**like.inc.php:**

```
function post_exists($id) {
    $host = "example";
    $username = "example";
    $password = "example";
    $database = "example";

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `count` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'");

    while ( $row = $objQuery->fetch_object() ) {
            if ( $row->count == 1 ) return true;
}
}
```

**profile.php:**

```
include ( 'like.inc.php' );

    if (post_exists(70) === true) {
        echo 'Exists!';
    }
```

A post with ID 70 exists, so it should echo Exists! but instead it just crashes half of my page. So maybe it's not loaded correctly?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $query->fetch_object()

Comment: Since you have warnings turned off, you're not going to see the "Warning: $objQuery not an object" or whatever.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks! Much Appreciated. My friend wrote this code. I did not notice that he misspelled something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have `$objQuery` must by `$query`. Try with this code:

```
 function post_exists($id) {
        $host = "example";
        $username = "example";
        $password = "example";
        $database = "example";

        $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

        $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

        $query = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `count` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'");

        while ( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
                if ( $row->count == 1 ) return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: @ChrisDekker This question should be deleted, because it won't serve anyone in the future, since it only was a single simple typo

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function in a different way like so:

```
function post_exists($id) {
    $host = "example";
    $username = "example";
    $password = "example";
    $database = "example";

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    // Instead of getting count, just get the row and 
    // do the count with PHP
    $query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1");

    if($query){
        return $query->num_rows > 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```